# Parsing a returned JSON via a GET call

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, parsing

I'm not really sure what I'm missing.My ajax call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({

                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "NaiveSentiment/commentValues",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#naiveComments').append("<ul id='newList'></ul>");
                            var keys = Object.keys(result);
                            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                                var key = keys[i];
                               // console.log(key, result[key]);
                                $("#newList").append("<li>" + result[key] + "</li>");
                            }
```

The method called look like this:

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public JsonResult commentValues()
    {

        NaiveAnalysisAction naiveAnalysisAction = new NaiveAnalysisAction();
        return Json(naiveAnalysisAction.getCommentAndValues(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

and the getCommentAndvalues() method:

```
 public String getCommentAndValues()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(commentAndValue);  
    }
```

The call is successful and I get the following result:
[image]

Where the "Text" part is an actual youtube comment and the number is actually a value I added based on the sentimental value of the comment.As you could see,everything is stored in a Dictionary which gets returned as a Json Object.That dictionary got as the "key" the text part and as value the number part.

My question is what should I change in order to successfully update the unordered list with the actual KEY (the comment itself?) the way I posted does a strange thing:The output is actually like a parser in which i'm reading by each character.So instead of displaying the full text it chuncks it in characters and display each letter one by one

[image]

Comment: `return Json()` serializes your object. You do not need to serialize it a 2nd time using `SerializeObject()`

Comment: Since you are using mvc, why not create a partial view and format the html there instead of in javascript in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke awesome catch Stephen! Somehow I missed that!

Comment: @Fran to be honest,i'm not really familiar with what are you trying to say,but  I will look it up.Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code its always  work for me

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'Ur Url/commentValues',
                    type: 'GET',                        
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
                });
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public object commentValues()
        {
            try
            {                                                         
                    var Result =naiveAnalysisAction.getCommentAndValues()
                    return new { IsError = false, DataList = Result };

             }   

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return null;
        }
```